# Change TFS Server Mapping

Tags: tfs

Running VS 2010, I want to now build on TFS 2010.

Originally I connected TFS server "tfs1". Now I want to map my local path to new TFS server "tfs2".
How to disconnect my old mapping with tfs1?
I got an error:

```
The path C:\test\xxxAdmin is already mapped in workspace aaa-PC[http://tfs1:8080/tfs/windowsapp]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source control explorer for your old server, you can drop down the "Workspaces" list, choose "Manage workspaces," and delete the workspace you no longer want to use.

Comment: The only thing I can do is delete the local folder,and create a new one. Mapping the server and local folder. If I keep the old one, the error will come back even I remove it.

Comment: I didn't say to delete the folder, I said to delete the workspace.  Works fine here!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you can go to the directory in question ("C:\test\xxxAdmin") in a VS command window (Start->All Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Visual Studio Tools\Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)) and then enter "**tf workspace**". Unless things are a bit screwy this will bring up the GUI "Edit Workspace". Find the directory in the "Working Folders" list, select it, and click "Remove".

You should now be able to create the new mapping

Comment: I removed it from VS 2010 GUI, but I can not add new one. The error comes back again.

Comment: Sounds like something is a bit off in your TFS...take a look at it with Sidekicks. http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Answer (score 0):

Select `Manage workspaces` and delete the workspace that you don't need.

[image]

You can also use tool `Tfs Workspace`

[image]